# How to convert my .dat file to csv to later display in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dataframe

MyCode:

```
import csv



# read flash.dat to a list of lists
datContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open("./subject101.dat").readlines()]

# write it as a new CSV file
with open("./flash.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(datContent)
```

Error:

```
<ipython-input-10-6943df295ef7> in <module>()
  7 with open("./subject101.csv", "wb") as f:
      8     writer = csv.writer(f)
----> 9     writer.writerows(datContent)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

MY .dat file

```
8.38 0 104 30 2.37223 8.60074 3.51048 2.43954 8.76165 3.35465 -0.0922174 0.0568115 -0.0158445 14.6806 -69.2128 -5.58905 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.23808 9.80003 -1.68896 0.265304 9.81549 -1.41344 -0.00506495 -0.00678097 -0.00566295 0.47196 -51.0499 43.2903 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.65918 -1.65569 -0.0997967 9.64689 -1.55576 0.310404 0.00830026 0.00925038 -0.0175803 -61.1888 -38.9599 -58.1438 1 0 0 0
8.39 0 NaN 30 2.18837 8.5656 3.66179 2.39494 8.55081 3.64207 -0.0244132 0.0477585 0.00647434 14.8991 -69.2224 -5.82311 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.31953 9.61282 -1.49328 0.234939 9.78539 -1.42846 0.013685 0.00148646 -0.0415218 1.0169 -50.3966 43.1768 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.6937 -1.57902 -0.215687 9.6167 -1.6163 0.280488 -0.00657665 -0.00463778 0.00036825 -59.8479 -38.8919 -58.5253 1 0 0 0
8.4 0 NaN 30 2.37357 8.60107 3.54898 2.30514 8.53644 3.7328 -0.0579761 0.0325743 -0.00698815 14.242 -69.5197 -5.12442 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.235593 9.72421 -1.76621 0.17385 9.72528 -1.51894 -0.0399232 0.0340559 -0.002113 0.383136 -51.8336 43.7782 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.58944 -1.73276 0.0929141 9.63173 -1.58605 0.280311 0.00301426 0.000148236 0.022495 -60.7361 -39.4138 -58.3999 1 0 0 0
8.41 0 NaN 30 2.07473 8.52853 3.66021 2.33528 8.53622 3.73277 -0.0023516 0.0328098 -0.00374727 14.8908 -69.5439 -6.17367 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.388697 9.53572 -1.7241 0.157969 9.64994 -1.57952 0.00751315 -0.0104983 -0.020684 0.3154 -49.8144 43.167 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.58814 -1.7704 0.0545449 9.63197 -1.63135 0.340997 0.00317498 -0.0203009 0.0112754 -60.4091 -38.7635 -58.3956 1 0 0 0
8.42 0 NaN 30 2.22936 8.83122 3.7 2.23055 8.59741 3.76295 0.0122691 0.018305 -0.0533248 15.5612 -68.8196 -6.28927 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.3158 9.49908 -1.60914 0.233506 9.57411 -1.44418 -0.00382244 -0.0112166 -0.0259745 -0.297733 -51.8097 43.6453 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.69771 -1.65625 -0.0608086 9.64699 -1.64647 0.340965 0.0126977 -0.0143027 -0.00282262 -61.5199 -39.3879 -58.2694 1 0 0 0
8.43 0 NaN 30 2.29959 8.82929 3.5471 2.26132 8.65762 3.77788 0.00323826 0.0122597 -0.0544735 15.4565 -68.818 -5.94087 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.321072 9.76369 -1.45502 0.264123 9.5588 -1.33862 0.0117016 0.0177607 -0.0364899 -0.00706324 -50.3645 43.4065 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.69551 -1.6556 -0.138014 9.64687 -1.61626 0.310598 -0.00608907 -0.0160236 0.00105049 -60.2954 -38.8778 -58.3977 1 0 0 0
8.44 0 NaN 30 2.33738 8.829 3.54767 2.27703 8.77828 3.7323 -0.0237041 -0.0315184 -0.0478827 15.1206 -68.5794 -6.05018 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.323161 9.68891 -1.37729 0.250395 9.69457 -1.26258 0.018062 0.00287833 -0.0306693 0.951744 -51.7342 43.0515 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.73474 -1.73242 -0.0599561 9.67704 -1.61621 0.340709 -0.0319725 -0.0539344 0.0155939 -60.6307 -38.8676 -58.2711 1 0 0 0
8.45 0 NaN 30 2.37142 9.055 3.39347 2.39786 8.89814 3.64131 0.019069 -0.022004 -0.0336473 14.8919 -68.7808 -6.28119 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.244544 9.65097 -1.45604 0.236025 9.80025 -1.26219 -0.0427185 -0.00489113 -0.0195477 0.240777 -50.9304 43.2869 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.70231 -1.61956 0.0933692 9.66183 -1.61627 0.295384 -0.0196432 -0.0399371 -0.000784916 -60.5171 -38.9819 -58.2733 1 0 0 0
8.46 0 NaN 30 2.33951 9.13251 3.54668 2.44371 8.98841 3.62596 0.02484 -0.0530542 -0.0111776 14.5769 -68.9936 -5.23831 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.309236 9.61049 -1.84194 0.220234 9.72488 -1.30765 0.00658695 0.0139032 -0.0125399 -0.106291 -50.8104 43.6495 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.73903 -1.54354 0.0546844 9.67713 -1.52545 0.355551 0.0137475 -0.010042 0.0177013 -61.2916 -39.6182 -58.1499 1 0 0 0
8.47 0 NaN 30 2.25966 9.09415 3.43015 2.42877 9.01871 3.61081 0.00762679 -0.0577595 -0.0190747 14.9037 -69.2257 -5.59174 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.234051 9.57333 -1.80446 0.188783 9.67993 -1.48894 -0.0176479 -0.00012583 -0.0108329 0.135296 -51.2677 43.8977 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.73624 -1.6568 -0.0218205 9.647 -1.60109 0.340819 0.00764948 -0.0139234 0.0144979 -60.8509 -39.0821 -58.1478 1 0 0 0
8.48 0 104 30 2.29745 8.9045 3.46984 2.39736 8.94335 3.53551 -0.0153703 -0.0658939 -0.0263224 15.131 -68.8051 -5.47408 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.237283 9.49881 -1.688 0.218302 9.61953 -1.51952 -0.00499829 0.0105328 -0.00972645 0.216756 -50.1418 42.6747 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.77736 -1.58207 0.0939061 9.63187 -1.52551 0.310386 0.0789 0.0022829 0.0203516 -61.5302 -38.724 -58.386 1 0 0 0
8.49 0 NaN 30 2.29531 8.79035 3.43171 2.42598 8.79209 3.50561 -0.013998 -0.0408748 -0.0296748 15.1348 -68.4804 -5.3549 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.355556 9.68749 -1.57031 0.293497 9.58913 -1.48983 -0.0268919 -0.0183369 -0.0389307 -0.180154 -51.9253 43.6469 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.69771 -1.65625 -0.0608086 9.61673 -1.52555 0.280196 0.0601758 0.0043882 0.00377953 -60.6221 -39.2053 -57.7797 1 0 0 0
8.5 0 NaN 30 2.44995 8.71431 3.54974 2.44016 8.70136 3.49069 -0.0280076 -0.0486606 -0.0301091 15.4776 -68.7238 -4.89853 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.354014 9.53662 -1.60857 0.264056 9.61928 -1.41401 0.020264 0.0545802 -0.0325681 0.500715 -51.9493 43.7798 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.62226 -1.76968 -0.0608784 9.63187 -1.54064 0.310435 0.0401132 -0.0356453 -0.00688931 -60.5181 -38.9803 -58.397 1 0 0 0
8.51 0 NaN 30 2.48078 8.86376 3.31878 2.45511 8.71633 3.46044 0.0410599 -0.0664342 -0.0214248 15.0175 -69.2337 -5.47741 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.354413 9.68723 -1.60905 0.234436 9.64947 -1.3684 -0.0138768 -0.0163511 -0.052388 0.602398 -51.6175 43.7818 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.73683 -1.5429 -0.0225213 9.67679 -1.60116 0.280121 0.0121161 -0.0068504 0.00748634 -60.7541 -38.1982 -58.5105 1 0 0 0
8.52 0 NaN 30 2.59174 8.90015 3.24334 2.48551 8.79158 3.41494 0.0709175 -0.0477612 -0.0304593 16.4541 -68.7624 -6.29888 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.359187 9.76358 -1.45433 0.189413 9.67978 -1.38315 0.0277015 0.0204268 -0.0437956 0.742886 -52.2881 43.2927 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.73734 -1.65712 0.0167824 9.67673 -1.60118 0.264986 0.042006 0.0221133 0.00468567 -60.9661 -38.8574 -58.1445 1 0 0 0
8.53 0 NaN 30 2.52044 8.93968 3.3576 2.53136 8.86676 3.41473 0.0346538 -0.0676665 -0.0315755 15.0108 -68.6834 -5.93431 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.317541 9.72526 -1.57112 0.17448 9.72513 -1.41316 -0.0113218 0.0212036 -0.0454249 0.378403 -51.7228 43.9008 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.66249 -1.65665 0.0160118 9.67685 -1.61627 0.295304 0.0160102 -0.0190713 0.0168348 -60.5186 -38.8716 -58.2721 1 0 0 0
8.54 0 NaN 30 2.52392 9.05417 3.43424 2.53098 8.88181 3.35429 0.0736048 -0.0329702 -0.0115635 14.6708 -68.3328 -6.27382 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.316198 9.6497 -1.60962 0.220174 9.80048 -1.3981 0.0193936 0.00184005 -0.0905627 0.370278 -51.3817 43.2883 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.73663 -1.58087 -0.0222877 9.69182 -1.57091 0.279943 0.012354 0.00046419 0.0083433 -61.409 -38.9587 -57.6468 1 0 0 0
8.55 0 NaN 30 2.44406 9.01581 3.31771 2.47082 8.86717 3.38459 0.0758924 -0.0195365 -0.0111 14.8973 -69.112 -5.93763 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.272763 9.79914 -1.8045 0.204934 9.75521 -1.38303 -0.0109559 -0.00811978 -0.0535057 -0.19757 -51.48 43.8924 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.77346 -1.69501 -0.0212016 9.63155 -1.55585 0.234809 0.0395772 0.00090798 -0.00969887 -60.6231 -39.2037 -57.9034 1 0 0 0
8.56 0 NaN 30 2.14121 8.7529 3.35255 2.39648 8.95835 3.41467 0.0363773 -0.0174136 -0.0299307 15.4592 -69.2563 -5.71416 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.274652 9.64904 -1.72653 0.204658 9.74016 -1.4133 0.0639872 0.00813986 -0.0410638 0.133601 -51.1526 43.5301 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.66299 -1.77088 0.0553154 9.58667 -1.58606 0.280551 0.00391491 -0.0511005 0.0204413 -59.8381 -39.6628 -58.6574 1 0 0 0
8.57 0 NaN 30 2.36714 9.01606 3.27807 2.4113 8.89786 3.44499 0.032675 0.0109087 -0.0315715 15.4647 -69.042 -5.48046 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.238626 9.57437 -1.6495 0.189533 9.75533 -1.44339 0.0339449 0.00337114 -0.0500734 0.561897 -50.4998 43.9053 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.69861 -1.69453 -0.0219722 9.60157 -1.57097 0.250153 -0.0024825 -0.0371737 0.0103145 -60.8494 -38.9767 -57.7754 1 0 0 0
8.58 0 NaN 30 2.48158 8.97758 3.31841 2.39661 8.98854 3.3995 0.0494165 0.0317889 -0.0131313 15.3622 -68.0598 -5.23724 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.160309 9.6494 -1.72861 0.189245 9.71005 -1.44352 0.00747992 -0.00420446 -0.0441058 -0.405668 -52.0329 44.0111 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.77346 -1.69501 -0.0212016 9.61673 -1.52555 0.280196 0.0132089 -0.0263304 0.0128207 -61.2995 -38.6348 -57.3967 1 0 0 0
8.59 0 104 30 2.40867 9.16819 3.35516 2.48704 9.03315 3.35401 0.0320149 0.0174556 -0.00630088 15.6885 -68.4006 -5.59184 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.204242 9.68823 -1.53433 0.174474 9.71002 -1.39809 0.0201247 -0.00912644 -0.00825804 0.280342 -51.9318 42.6733 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.62446 -1.77032 0.0163273 9.64682 -1.58603 0.295366 0.00404562 0.00579102 0.0217629 -61.0729 -39.5091 -58.6457 1 0 0 0
8.6 0 NaN 30 2.51883 9.28013 3.24097 2.56265 9.0779 3.33873 0.00653855 0.0412912 -0.0351101 15.3468 -68.9219 -5.825 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.315353 9.7624 -1.64872 0.188862 9.64968 -1.44369 0.00779826 -0.0554575 -0.0263168 0.738912 -52.1763 43.2928 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.65989 -1.73195 -0.0607267 9.64696 -1.54061 0.32549 0.0276717 -0.00225061 0.0319903 -60.3995 -38.8871 -57.4068 1 0 0 0
8.61 0 NaN 30 2.36955 9.16815 3.31608 2.53225 9.04791 3.33883 -0.031668 0.0348366 -0.032475 15.3403 -67.826 -6.39176 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.274553 9.61139 -1.72641 0.188574 9.6044 -1.44382 -0.00547973 -0.0128856 0.00972958 0.255914 -51.379 43.4091 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.66138 -1.65633 -0.022591 9.61684 -1.55576 0.310563 -0.00647589 -0.0296264 0.0182522 -60.744 -38.6463 -58.0203 1 0 0 0
8.62 0 NaN 30 2.48372 9.09173 3.35654 2.48843 9.07856 3.47471 -0.0163176 -0.011364 -0.0195608 15.7884 -68.9445 -6.06176 1 0 0 0 31.8125 0.31953 9.61282 -1.49328 0.234076 9.64956 -1.42885 -0.00685788 -0.0266579 0.00261903 0.00164464 -50.5872 43.2837 1 0 0 0 30.3125 9.58394 -1.73115 -0.1001 9.64683 -1.54065 0.29522 -0.0259621 -0.0250197 0.00485252 -60.9646 -38.752 -57.772 1 0 0 0
```

not sure what the 1 0 0 0 labels are and what to do with them so far so if you have a suggestion please tell me.

i wanted to convert it to csv so that later I can display and play around with data in a dataframe using the code below

```
import pandas as pd

def your_func(row):
    return row['x-momentum'] / row['mass']

columns_to_keep = ['#time', 'x-momentum', 'mass']
dataframe = pd.read_csv("./flash.csv", usecols=columns_to_keep)
dataframe['new_column'] = dataframe.apply(your_func, axis=1)

print dataframe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer is incorrect. I tested your code and found the issue. Instead of `open("./flash.csv", "wb")`, use:

```
open("./flash.csv", "w")
```

Apparently csv writer expected binary mode in 2.7, but expects text mode in python 3+

Comment: it worked!, thanx btw do you have an idea of what the 1000 can mean it seems like they are seperating the actual data kinda dont want to use them if they are not important, I am using the data from here http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/pamap2+physical+activity+monitoring

Comment: The data set description file linked [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00231/readme.pdf) seems to describe those columns as "14-17 orientation (invalid in this data collection)". Not sure what they indicate beyond that, but if it says invalid, my guess is that they are not important.